# Customized URL in Google app engine

Tags: html, google-app-engine, url

I am working in Google app engine, i have created on website in which several tabs are like **home**  **about us**..

When i click on Home tab the url is like `http://localhost:8080/#home`

How can i make it like `http://localhost:8080/Home` , `http://localhost:8080/AboutUs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should not be using # in your URL as # is a client side anchor. All the processing of # is handled on your browser and the information #home is not passed to the server.

You should be using proper URLs in your links instead of using #

Comment: Thank you very much . Will you please explain how to do that ?